# Cannot get 'fa fa-search' to work

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I am trying to get 'fa fa-search' to work inside an input box, but it doesn't work. I have seen other questions on the same one, but they did not work for me. Can someone point out the problem.

```
<div>
        <input
            type="text" 
            placeholder="Enter Search Text" 
            value={this.props.queryText}
            ref="queryInput"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            className="searchBar"
            type="text"
        />
        <i className="abc fa fa-search"></i>

</div>
```

Here is my CSS code

```
.searchBar{
    width: 380px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.abc{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    left: -25px;
}
```

I am using ReactJS, Bootstrap along with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you have attached necessary files to make font-awesome work.

```css
.searchBar {
    width: 380px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.abc {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    left: -30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
    <input
        type="text" 
        placeholder="Enter Search Text" 
        value={this.props.queryText}
        ref="queryInput"
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        class="searchBar"
        type="text"
    />
    <i class="abc fa fa-search"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: I am using className for reasons and it works. I was missing <link href> for font-awesome. If you can edit and remove className part, I can accept your answer as I got the solution from you.

Comment: **To the downvoter** May i know the reason for your downvote??

Answer (score 0):

It's `class` not `className`

```
<div>
        <input
            type="text" 
            placeholder="Enter Search Text" 
            value={this.props.queryText}
            ref="queryInput"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            class="searchBar"
            type="text"
        />
        <i class="abc fa fa-search"></i>

</div>
```